# How to find screen DPI on Mir in Ubuntu Touch from command line

Tags: mir, dpi

I know that in X display server you can do:

> $ xdpyinfo | grep dots

but how to achieve this in Mir display server on Ubuntu Touch, where there is no xdpyinfo?

Answer (score 1):

I found help at Ubuntu App Dev group on Telegram, from Michael Zanetti, he pointed me out to mirout tool (/usr/bin/mirout):

> $ MIR_SOCKET=/var/run/mir_socket mirout

here, the MIR_SOCKET variable serves similar purpose ad DISPLAY variable would on X display server.

This tool spits out the screen resolution and physical dimension of the screen, like this (from Meizu MX4 Ubuntu Edition):

> Connected to server:  Card 0: Max 3 simultaneous outputs
>
> Output 1: Card 0, LVDS, connected, 1152x1920+0+0, used, on, 60mm x
>
> 101mm (4.6"), normal
>
> ```
> 1152x1920     60.72*+ Output 2: Card 0, DisplayPort, disconnected Output 3: Card 0, Virtual, disconnected
>
> 1920x1080     60.00*+
> ```

So you just need a simple math to get the DPI:

> DPI = √(w²+h²) / diagonal

So in this example :

> DPI = √(1152²+1920²) / 4.6"
>
> DPI = 2239.085527621 / 4.6"
>
> DPI = approximately 486